# Word for a redundant, repeated action that has no effect on the outcome of a task

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the word for something where no matter how many times we repeat an action, it has no bearing on the outcome?

e.g. pressing the 'close doors' button on an elevator repeatedly doesn't make the doors close faster.

e.g. repeatedly clicking the mouse when your computer freezes doesn't help it unfreeze.

Example sentence:

*"Repeatedly pressing the 'close doors' button in an elevator is a [insert word here] action"*

Comment: Hello, Jack, and welcome to EL&U. While your question is quite interesting, it would benefit from including a sample sentence with a blank for the target language.

Comment: @Cascabel Hmm, not too sure how it could be used in a sentence. Other than saying "repeatedly pressing the 'close doors' button in an elevator is a [insert word here] action"

Comment: I see Cascabel is beating a dead horse again.

Comment: @HotLicks Ever read _Red Sky at Morning_? The "best" way to play "beat a dead horse" is it's gotta be left out in the sun for a couple days, the longer the better, and  you gotta actually fall into it, guts and all. Seriously...I been away for awhile. It's no longer a requirement, or am I just flogging my norton?

Comment: @Cascabel - Will you get off your high horse!  (Or at least quit gunning the engine.)

Comment: What kind of engine does a high-horse have? A V-8 4 barrel? @HotLicks

Comment: @Cascabel - Whatever it is, I'm sure it would be one Boss Hoss!

Comment: I actually worked on a computer system that would occasionally freeze up, but the interrupts generated by moving the mouse around would allow the kernel to do another round of scheduling before locking up again.  So you had to continuously move the mouse while typing the "kill process command"

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest the word **Futile.**

According to [Cambridge dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/futile?topic=useless-and-futile):

> (of actions) having no effect or achieving nothing
>
> > "His men made repeated but ultimately ***futile*** attempts to retrieve his body from no-man's land."

Synonyms: *fruitless, vain, pointless*.

Answer (score 0):

You could call it:

[**ineffectual**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ineffectual)

> not producing the proper or intended effect

-Merriam Webster online

i.e.

> Repeatedly pressing the 'close doors' button in an elevator is an ***ineffectual*** action

Not a single word, but:

***illusion of control***

> The illusion of control is the tendency for people to overestimate their ability to control events; for example, it occurs when someone feels a sense of control over outcomes that they demonstrably do not influence.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusion_of_control#CITEREFThompson1999)

It is a type of cognitive bias sometimes called a positive illusion. Sorry for the Wiki quote...still struggling through Thompson and Angler to find a better source.

You might find [this post](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/4423/why-do-people-press-elevator-call-buttons-repeatedly) on Psychology and Neuroscience.SE (beta) relevant.

Comment: Hi Cascabel, thank you for your detailed answer. Now, I may be imagining things but I am 95% sure that I read something somewhere about a single word for such an action. So, for now, I won't mark this as the accepted answer

Comment: @jackchmbrln if you have any other clues please include feel free to edit your Q....BTW...you still need to include a sample sentence. Please think about the part of speech.

Answer (score 0):

An action is **idempotent** if performing it multiple times has the same effect as performing it just once.

> Pressing the 'close doors' button in an elevator is an **idempotent** action

Answer (score 0):

A repeated but unnecessary action could be called **[redundant](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/redundant)**.

Note: I was going to suggest *idempotent*, but had to content myself with upvoting an answer that beat me to the punch!

Answer (score 0):

**Superfluous** unnecessary, especially through being more than enough. [Source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/superfluous)

Comment: please add a source for your definition

Answer (score -1):

an **effete** action or result [TFD](https://www.freethesaurus.com/effete)

> depleted of vitality, force, or effectiveness; exhausted

As in:

With his screen frozen, he resorted to the **effete** and repetitive clicking of the computer mouse.